# How to use file picker in android app

Tags: java, android, filepicker.io, filepicker

I am developing a simple android app, I want to use file picker when I press button, so how can I implement file picker in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time earlier figuring this out so to wrap up

> Intents provide the ability to hook into third-party app components
>   for content selection. This works well for media files, but if you
>   want users to be able to select any file, they must have an existing
>   "file explorer" app installed. Because many Android devices don't have
>   stock File Explorers, the developer must often instruct the user to
>   install one, or build one, themselves. aFileChooser solves this issue.

You can clone it from [iPaulPro/aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser).